# Json create searchable URL

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring

I am currently building a webapp that uses a Spring-boot backend and an Angular 2 frontend.

The backend simply exposes some Json data (about employees) to localhost in this format on localhost:8080:

```
{
name: "John Smith",
mail: "john@example.com",
id: 0
},
{
name: "George Bach"
mail: "George@example.com",
id: 1
},
```

What I want to do is to be able to search through the Json URL so that I can type in `"localhost:8080/?mail=john@example.com"` and it would show me just John's object details.

What is the standard way to do this? Also is it better to implement something like this in the Spring backend or the angular front end?

Comment: Standards are defined by the requirements. If you need backend related operations e.g. input validations, go for backend implementation. Else, if you just want to filter out your JSON based on the given inputs, there are a lot of methods out there to do this. You will need to get the value of query parameter, and write the logic of JSON filtering in your angular controller/service.

Comment: Is there any guide on how to do it on the backend?

Comment: Give a hit to Spring MVC. It will help you get data from server based on the given inputs.

Comment: Youd can try this out of the box example of spring-data-rest queryDSL https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/web/querydsl. QueryDsl is a dsl package which tresolves your entity properties from/to given web parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering and searching is normally done on the server that conceptually owns the data. This is because it is usually faster and it enables different clients to share the same functionality. Also the storage layer usually provides search/filtering functionality so it's really a matter of converting the API to the storage layer interface.

A good starting point for the API is https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and following up with storage http://mrbool.com/rest-server-with-spring-data-spring-boot-and-postgresql/34023

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass "id" Instead of passing full "mail". because it's not a good practice by using this url can be longer .

Then take id in your controller using :

```
 $scope.userId=$stateParmas.id;
```

Inject $stateParams in your controller

Then in ng-repeat apply filter using id:

```
ng-repeat="item in urArray | filter:id";
```

it will give you the filtered array by id